# How can i get customer id after successfull signup?

Tags: magento

I have make custom module in which I have make observer file. the observer file calls successfully after 'customer_save_after' event.
Now I want to write some custom code on observer file. For this I want to get last save user id. for this I am using following code.
"echo $id = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();"
But nothing is print by this.
How can I get the customer id here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you'd better extract the customer from observer. The good piece of code might be [here](http://www.fontis.com.au/blog/magento/automatically-set-magento-customer-group)